# Processes with python multiprocessing not ending

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing

Trying to get multiprocessing working correctly. Have review lots of posts in Stack overflow but none seem to fit my issue. I have a batch of pdfs that I am extracting the text data from. Using multiprocessing with queue to speed up the process. My script starts the processes and extracts the text from the pdfs.

There is a print statement in the main.py that is never executed saying that there are processes that never finish.

```
print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} seconds(s)')
```

My main.py read as

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import freeze_support, Queue  # Add this line to support Windows platform
import ExtractPDFData as eD
import time
import os


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    files_to_process = []
    pdf_directory = 'PDFData'

    for each_pdf_file in os.listdir(pdf_directory):
        if each_pdf_file.endswith('.pdf'):
            files_to_process.append(os.path.join(pdf_directory, each_pdf_file))

    start = time.perf_counter()
    q = Queue()
    current_processes_array = []

    for pdf_file in files_to_process:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=eD.pdf_process, args=(pdf_file, q))
        p.start()
        current_processes_array.append(p)

    print(f"Number of active children: {len(multiprocessing.active_children())}")

    for process in current_processes_array:
        process.join()

    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} seconds(s)')

    with open('OutputData/halo_data.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as add_text_to_file:
        while not q.empty():
            add_text_to_file.write(q.get())
        add_text_to_file.close()

    with open('OutputData/halo_data.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as f:
        print(f'Number of char in the input file: {len(f.read())}')
```

The attaching ExtractedPDFData.py is

```
from pypdf import PdfReader
import os


# Extracts text from PDF file
def pdf_process(pdf_path, q):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as f:
        reader = PdfReader(f)
        cleaned_pages_array = []

        for page in range(len(reader.pages)):
            # Extract the text from each page
            page_of_text = reader.pages[page].extract_text()
            # Convert to lowercase
            page_of_text = page_of_text.lower()
            # Remove non-alphanumeric characters and extra whitespaces
            cleaned_pages_array.append(page_of_text)

        print('Number of pages in the array: ', len(cleaned_pages_array))
        text = " ".join(cleaned_pages_array)
        q.put(text)

        print("Have written to file " + pdf_path)

        print(f"Worker process ID: {os.getpid()}, which comes from the parent {os.getppid()}")
```

Comment: Consume the queue before join. Even better, don't use a queue - it's really not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because the queue has not been consumed before attempting *join()* on each of the sub-processes.

In fact, using a queue in this case only serves to makes matters more complex than they need to be. One could simply return the relevant data from the subprocesses and collect that in the main program.

However, OP want to use a queue so here's a safer way to do that.

First of all, we can simplify this:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

def pdf_process(path, q):
    reader = PdfReader(path)
    fix = [_p.extract_text().lower() for _p in reader.pages]
    q.put(' '.join(fix))
```

...then...

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from ExtractPDFData import pdf_process
from time import perf_counter
from glob import glob

NPROCS = 9 # tested on 10-core machine so leave one spare

OUTPUT = '/Volumes/G-Drive/halo_data.txt'
INPUT = '/Volumes/G-Drive/Downloads/*.pdf'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        start = perf_counter()
        q = manager.Queue()
        with Pool(NPROCS) as pool:
            with open(OUTPUT, 'w') as add_text_to_file:
                args = [(_f, q) for _f in glob(INPUT)]
                for _ in pool.starmap(pdf_process, args):
                    add_text_to_file.write(q.get())

        print(f'Finished in {perf_counter()-start:.2f}s')

        with open(OUTPUT) as f:
            print(f'Output file size = {len(f.read())} bytes')
```

In testing, 20 PDFs each with an average of 20 pages, runs in <2s after producing an output file with >520,000 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Your code look good, the processes might take a long time to finish their tasks which cause your problem, you could check that with a print before the `for process in current_processes_array:`

If it is that we could use `ThreadPoolExecutor` to handle parallelism and process management for us.

```
import os
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import ExtractPDFData as eD

pdf_directory = 'PDFData'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files_to_process = [
        os.path.join(pdf_directory, file)
        for file in os.listdir(pdf_directory)
        if file.endswith('.pdf')
    ]

    start = time.perf_counter()
    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(eD.pdf_process, files_to_process)
        text_data = list(results)

    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} seconds(s)')

    with open('OutputData/halo_data.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as add_text_to_file:
        for text in text_data:
            add_text_to_file.write(text)

    with open('OutputData/halo_data.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as f:
        print(f'Number of char in the input file: {len(f.read())}')
```

Dont forget to modify `pdf_process` function in `ExtractPDFData.py`.

```
def pdf_process(pdf_path):
    ...
    return text
```

You could also try to optimize `ExtractPDFData.py`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `multiprocessing.Queue` is a process shared queue that needs to be consumed **before** the process is terminated/joined.
From doc ([guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines)):

> Joining processes that use queues
>
> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the
> “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call
> the `Queue.cancel_join_thread` method of the queue to avoid this
> behaviour.)
>
> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be
> removed before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure
> that processes which have put items on the queue will terminate.
> Remember also that non-daemonic processes will be joined
> automatically.

So the options you have are a) calling `q.cancel_join_thread()` withing a process or b) consuming the queue `q.get()` before joining processes with `process.join()`.

Answer (score 0):

I took the point that the 'queue' needs to be consumed before 'join()'. Tested that premise but my script still didn't work. The premise however was correct but is seems it is what I putting in the 'queue' that is causing the issue - 'queue' and 'process' with big text files isn't that right mix.

When I altered my code to 'put' string values into the 'queue' instead of big 'text' files and the script ran successfully. I then placed the big text files into an object and 'put' those object reference values to the 'queue', but that didn't work. I really thought that would be successful.

So small values work but not large text files, or reference values.

Next step is to look at 'Pooling'.